# getActionBar() returns null where Main Activity extends FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to learn Swipe tabs in android fragments using 3 tabs by referring to a tutorial. I am getting null pointer exception in the line:

```
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

since the the following line is returning null

```
actionBar=getActionBar();
```

Here is the full code.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.pricababa.learningswipetabs;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    ActionBar actionBar;
    ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();

        viewPager= (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(fragmentManager));
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i1) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int i) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(i);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

            }
        });

        actionBar=getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        ActionBar.Tab tab1=actionBar.newTab();
        tab1.setText("Tab 1");
        tab1.setTabListener(this);

        ActionBar.Tab tab2=actionBar.newTab();
        tab1.setText("Tab 2");
        tab1.setTabListener(this);

        ActionBar.Tab tab3=actionBar.newTab();
        tab1.setText("Tab 3");
        tab1.setTabListener(this);

        actionBar.addTab(tab1);
        actionBar.addTab(tab2);
        actionBar.addTab(tab3);

    }


    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

    }
}



class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{
    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
        super(fm);
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {

        Fragment fragment=null;
        if(i==0)
            fragment=new FragmentA();
        else if(i==1)
            fragment=new FragmentB();
        else if(i==2)
            fragment=new FragmentC();

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

I tried to apply the following fixes from similar SO threads:

1) `getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);`

2) using `getSupportActionBar()`

That didn't help. It would be very helpful if somebody can explain the reason behind this and state a possible fix.

Thanks!

EDIT: I am following this tutorial: 
[See here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iEl0ylVvZho&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW4lMlpHgL7UNQSGMERcDzHo&index=32)

Comment: Do you have any specific style that you use?

Comment: No I haven't used any

Comment: If you're compiling with the new Android APIs then you have to manually add the `Toolbar` (that's the new name of the Action Bar) in your layouts. And then in your Activity you find it via its id like `Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)`, you set it as the Action Bar for this Activity bi doing `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)` and finally you'll can make things like `getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My Title")`

Comment: That tutorial is almost 2 years old, `ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS` is deprecated. Use [`AppCompatActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html) to support action bar below API 14 and material design below API 21. Use new [`TabLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) for tabs.